# Using AngularJS in an embedded system without an internet connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, embedded, single-page-application, yocto

Good morning,

I am looking to implement a single page web application on an embedded system.  The catch is that it may not have an internet connection so I can't depend on external sources for features.

I would like to use AngularJS, but the system will not have the Node Package Manager installed.  Is it possible to deploy an Angular application through a standard web server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very much possible to run angular without npm on a standard web server. The key here is that AngularJs is a javascript library and doesn't rely on binaries. All you need to do is be able to connect to it from a browser.

If your html contains a link to the address of the file such as:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

As long as the browser has access to http://YourserverAddress/js/angular.min.js it should load angular in the same way as using npm or a CDN

Comment: I don't know how I missed this.  This is exactly what I've been looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I have a idea.
If the embedded system have a browser, I think it's possible.
The thing you just should to do is let your javascript source run in the browser.
So, customize the browser, let it run your source directly.